# Does windows 11 support individual Virtual Desktops per Display?

Tags: windows-11

I am in the middle of a hardware upgrade and cant find out myself. Can someone conclusively answer this for me?

Windows 10 treats all connected displays as one virtual desktop space, so switching virtual desktops in one display will cause all others to change.

This [article](https://winaero.com/windows-10-will-soon-have-individual-virtual-desktops-per-display/) here states that this feature was meant to come to Windows 10. Is this feature present in Windows 11 currently?

Comment: Windows 11 is not really out at this point, but on the pre-release I do have, virtual desktops are the same as Windows 10.

Comment: Yh I know, I am just eager to find out of this feature has finally been implemented as its the only thing will even make me bother with W11. Thanks!

Comment: I got to the newest Dev build for Windows 11 in the last couple of days and nothing like that yet.

Comment: Welp there goes W11 for me. at this rate I will probably master C++ and build  my own window manager.  Thanks for confirming it for me, John.